# Deadlock with multiples goroutines and one channel

Tags: go

I have a deadlock problem that I can not solve.

I own some urls, and every url in a goroutine will bring me enough data. This data I'm putting in a single channel. But if I close the channel the program does not work, if I leave the channel open deadlock appears.

I do not know how to solve, someone would have a solution

Below I put the problem in a simplified way

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type urlNumbers struct {
    url string
    numbers []int
}

func getNumbers(urls []urlNumbers) chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)

    for _, url := range urls {
        go allNumbersOfURL(url, ch)
    }

    return ch
}

func allNumbersOfURL(url urlNumbers, ch chan int) {
    for _, i := range url.numbers {
        ch <- i
    }
}

func main() {
    url1 := urlNumbers {url: "1", numbers: []int{1, 2, 3}}
    url2 := urlNumbers {url: "2", numbers: []int{4, 5, 6}}
    url3 := urlNumbers {url: "3", numbers: []int{7, 8, 9}}
    url4 := urlNumbers {url: "4", numbers: []int{10, 11, 12}}

    c := getNumbers([]urlNumbers{url1, url2, url3, url4})

    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }

    fmt.Println("END")

}
```

Output

```
go run app.go
10
11
12
4
7
1
2
3
5
6
8
9
fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `for i := range c` to iterate over a channel yet the code does not know when to stop. `range` over a channel waits until channel to be closed, or hang forever. That is why there is a deadlock.

You should close your channel after all "urls" are issued over the channel. This can be acheived with helps of [`sync.WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). In `getNumbers`, before the loop, you can use a `WaitGroup` and set number of jobs to wait as `len(urls)`:

```
wg:=&sync.WaitGroup{}
wg.Add(len(urls))
```

And add a new goroutine before returning `ch`:

```
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
} ()
```

And then in `allNumbersOfURL`, add the `WaitGroup` as a new param, and set a job done after the loop.

```
func allNumbersOfURL(url urlNumbers, ch chan int,wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    for _, i := range url.numbers {
        ch <- i
    }
    wg.Done()
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/--7x7eXIzP9

Answer (score 2):

channel must be closed, u can use `sync.WaitGroup` to wait for tasks done. Here's an modification to function `getNumbers`

```
func getNumbers(urls []urlNumbers) <-chan int {
    ch := make(chan int)

    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    for _, url := range urls {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(url urlNumbers, ch chan<- int) {
            defer wg.Done()
            allNumbersOfURL(url, ch)
        }(url, ch)
    }

    go func(wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan int) {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }(wg, ch)

    return ch
}
```

Additionally, I advice u use channel direction in argument delivering.

> The optional <- operator specifies the channel direction, send or
>   receive. If no direction is given, the channel is bidirectional.